# App crash when sliding cursor in edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an android app with a couple of edittexts around in different layouts. Every single on of them seem to crash my app when I slide the cursor (write something, press anywhere on the written string, and slide the little marker underneath) or when I press/hold to mark everything. I am able to recreate this on two different HTC one (android 5.0.2) with swiftkey and native keyboard. Could not recreate this on a Samsung Galaxy S6 (android 5.1.1) with native keyboard. I have tried compiling my app without debug, same situation. I have tried edittexts in other apps - they work fine.

One of my layout is as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/report_message_title"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_report_message_title"
    android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
    android:labelFor="@+id/fragment_report_message_edit_text"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_report_message_edit_text"
    android:layout_below="@+id/fragment_report_message_title"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/report_btn_send"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_report_btn_send"
    android:layout_below="@+id/fragment_report_message_edit_text"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The fragment that handles this code is as follows:

```
public class ReportFragment extends Fragment {
    private View mContentView;

    private TextView messageTitle;
    public static EditText messageField;
    public static Button sendButton;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mContentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_report, container, false);
        messageField = (EditText) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_report_message_edit_text);
        sendButton = (Button) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_report_btn_send);
        messageTitle = (TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_report_message_title);

        messageTitle.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.report_cancel_message_title));

        sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String message = messageField.getText().toString();
                if(message.matches("")){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Missing message!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    onButtonPressed(message);
                }
            }
        });
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return mContentView;
    }

    public void onButtonPressed(String message) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            sendButton.setEnabled(false);
            mListener.onSendButtonClicked(message,reportType);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                            + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        void onSendButtonClicked(String message, String reportType);
    }

}
```

From log cat (note that the first 6 lines occur before the crash - they are just included for completeness):

```
08-25 20:41:31.028  30275-30275/co.listedapp.listed E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
08-25 20:41:31.028  30275-30275/co.listedapp.listed E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
08-25 20:41:31.048  30275-30275/co.listedapp.listed E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
08-25 20:41:31.048  30275-30275/co.listedapp.listed E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
08-25 20:41:31.078  30275-30275/co.listedapp.listed E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
08-25 20:41:31.078  30275-30275/co.listedapp.listed E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
08-25 20:41:39.877  30275-30275/co.listedapp.listed E/InputEventReceiver﹕ Exception dispatching input event.
08-25 20:41:39.877  30275-30275/co.listedapp.listed E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
08-25 20:41:39.897  30275-30275/co.listedapp.listed E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class TextView
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.initContentView(Editor.java:3155)
            at android.widget.Editor$PinnedPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:2418)
            at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:3127)
            at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:3127)
            at android.widget.Editor$HandleView.showActionPopupWindow(Editor.java:3555)
            at android.widget.Editor$InsertionHandleView.showWithActionPopup(Editor.java:3896)
            at android.widget.Editor$InsertionHandleView.onTouchEvent(Editor.java:4016)
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8444)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8655)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4238)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4094)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3635)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3694)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3660)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3773)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3668)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3830)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3640)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3694)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3660)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3668)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3640)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5940)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5908)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5872)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6030)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:211)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:153)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:131)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
     Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=15; index=1321
            at android.content.res.StringBlock.get(StringBlock.java:65)
            at android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser.getPooledString(XmlBlock.java:458)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.loadStringValueAt(TypedArray.java:967)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getString(TypedArray.java:176)
            at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1030)
            at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:646)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:44)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:40)
            at android.support.v7.internal.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:103)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:802)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:832)
            at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.initContentView(Editor.java:3155)
            at android.widget.Editor$PinnedPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:2418)
            at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:3127)
            at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:3127)
            at android.widget.Editor$HandleView.showActionPopupWindow(Editor.java:3555)
            at android.widget.Editor$InsertionHandleView.showWithActionPopup(Editor.java:3896)
            at android.widget.Editor$InsertionHandleView.onTouchEvent(Editor.java:4016)
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8444)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8655)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4238)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4094)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3635)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3694)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3660)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3773)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3668)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3830)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3640)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3694)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3660)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3668)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3640)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5940)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5908)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5872)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6030)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:211)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:153)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:131)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
08-25 20:41:39.897  30275-30275/co.listedapp.listed E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: co.listedapp.listed, PID: 30275
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class TextView
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.initContentView(Editor.java:3155)
            at android.widget.Editor$PinnedPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:2418)
            at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:3127)
            at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:3127)
            at android.widget.Editor$HandleView.showActionPopupWindow(Editor.java:3555)
            at android.widget.Editor$InsertionHandleView.showWithActionPopup(Editor.java:3896)
            at android.widget.Editor$InsertionHandleView.onTouchEvent(Editor.java:4016)
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8444)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8655)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4238)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4094)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3635)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3694)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3660)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3773)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3668)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3830)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3640)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3694)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3660)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3668)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3640)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5940)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5908)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5872)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6030)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:211)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:153)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:131)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
     Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=15; index=1321
            at android.content.res.StringBlock.get(StringBlock.java:65)
            at android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser.getPooledString(XmlBlock.java:458)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.loadStringValueAt(TypedArray.java:967)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getString(TypedArray.java:176)
            at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1030)
            at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:646)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:44)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:40)
            at android.support.v7.internal.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:103)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:802)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:832)
            at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.initContentView(Editor.java:3155)
            at android.widget.Editor$PinnedPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:2418)
            at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:3127)
            at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:3127)
            at android.widget.Editor$HandleView.showActionPopupWindow(Editor.java:3555)
            at android.widget.Editor$InsertionHandleView.showWithActionPopup(Editor.java:3896)
            at android.widget.Editor$InsertionHandleView.onTouchEvent(Editor.java:4016)
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8444)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8655)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4238)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4094)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3635)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3694)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3660)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3773)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3668)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3830)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3640)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3694)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3660)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3668)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3640)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5940)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5908)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5872)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6030)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:211)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:153)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:131)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

Comment: Do you have support library integrated?

Comment: @android_Muncher We have the support library v4 and v7 is that is what you mean.

Comment: Are you using any custom themes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove any

```
<item name="android:fontFamily"></item>
```

in your styles.xml. If you want to read more about why it happens.I can elaborate.

Comment: Worked! Please elaborate or throw me a URL.

Comment: Hi @android_Muncher do you think you can share to me what's the cause of this error. Your answer saved me. I was using a custom font across my app and this exception occurs whenever i move the cursor in the edittext with custom font.